# Showing a placeholder/default img, if no featured image is set

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

I need to modify the following code to show a placeholder if there is no featured image available.

I understand that I need to add a `if` statement in the following code but wasn't sure of the exact coding I needed. Obviously in plain english it's going to be along the lines of if there is a thumbnail show it, if not show the placeholder.

```
<?php $rel = $related->show(get_the_ID(), true);
     $count = 1;
    foreach ($rel as $r) {
     $class= ($count%6 == 0)?"category-related-item-right":"";

     echo '<div class="category-related-item '.$class.'"><a href='.get_permalink($r->ID).'>'.'<div class=category-related-title>'.$r->post_title.'</div>'.get_the_post_thumbnail($r->ID, array(50,50)).'</a></div>';
$count++;
}?>
```

I've tried the following but something isn't quite right as it's breaking the page...

```
<?php $rel = $related->show(get_the_ID(), true);
$count = 1;
foreach ($rel as $r) {
$class= ($count%6 == 0)?"category-related-item-right":"";

echo '<div class="category-related-item '.$class.'"><a href='.get_permalink($r->ID).'>'.'<div class=category-related-title>'.$r->post_title.'</div>';
if (get_the_post_thumnail($r->ID)) : 
get_the_post_thumbnail($r->ID, array(50,50));
else :
echo '<img src="image_url"/>';
endif;
echo '</a></div>';
$count++;
}?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Misspelling of **thumbnail** (thumnail) in the if statement.

Also [`get_the_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) does echo the thumbnail, but just returns the html. You need to echo it.

Also, for checking if a post has a thumbnail, you can use [`has_post_thumbnail`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail).

```
 if ( has_post_thumbnail($r->ID)) {
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($r->ID, array(50,50));
 }else{
    echo '<img src="image_url"/>';
 }
```

Comment: Thanks... the smallest of things are always the cause of a headache!

Answer (score 1):

For designers who have less or no knowlege and for staters in wordpress to get image code is given here. Designers can just copy wordpress get image code and paste.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail($post->ID) ){   
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'full');
    $image = $image[0];
    echo '<div id="product" class="MagicZoomPlus" href="'.$image.'" rel="selectors-class: Active"><img src="'.$image.'" alt="" /></div>';
}else{  
    $image = get_template_directory_uri() .'/img/placeholder-580.png'; 
    echo '<a id="product" class="MagicZoomPlus" href="'.$image.'" rel="selectors-class: Active"><img src="'.$image.'" alt="" /></a>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### A function to add default images for themes

*The following code can also be found on Trac as Ticket <sup>1)</sup>.*

<sup>1) Please add yourself as @cc there to support it. Thanks!</sup>

**[Ticket Link](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18951)**

Using the function `wp_default_img()`:

> It works with an input array of attributes and offers two filters (wp_default_img_attr & wp_default_img). So setting up default images is as easy as using a filter (if the theme developer isn't satisfied with the functions default args) and finally just adding…

```
// functions.php during init:
add_image_size( 'default_img', 80, 80, true );

// Inside some template
$placeholder = get_site_url( null, 'your_path' ).'/some_img.jpg';
echo wp_default_img( array( 'url' => $placeholder, 'size' => 'default_img' ) );
```

> The function also cares about cropping images if 4th argument set to true when registering the size using add_image_size();.

```
function wp_default_img( $attr )
{
        // Sizes registered via add_image_size();
        global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;

        $defaults = array(
             'size'     => 'medium'
            ,'classes'  => false
            ,'alt'      => false
            ,'title'    => false
            ,'align'    => 'none'
            ,'echo'     => true 
        );

        $attr = wp_parse_args( $attr, $defaults );

        if ( 'thumb' === $attr['size'] )
            $attr['size'] = 'thumbnail';

        // Size in built in sizes - call size setting from DB
        # behavoir in here, dependent on outcome of @link http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18947
        if ( ! in_array( $attr['size'], array_keys( $_wp_additional_image_sizes ) ) )
        {
            $sizes                        = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
            // Get option - gladly autoloaded/can use wp_cache_get();
            $size_data['width']  = intval( get_option( "{$attr['size']}_size_w") );
            $size_data['height']= intval( get_option( "{$attr['size']}_size_h") );
            // Not sure how this will behave if cropped is false (autoloaded option not added)
            $size_data['crop']    = get_option( "{$attr['size']}_crop" ) ? get_option( "{$attr['size']}_crop" ) : false;
        }
        // Size array from global registered additional/custom sizes array
        else 
        {
            $size_data = $_wp_additional_image_sizes[ $attr['size'] ];
        }

        // Retrieve image width & height
        $img_info       = @getimagesize( $attr['url'] );

        // Calculate final dimensions - if "crop" was set to true during add_image_size(), the img will get ... cropped
        $end_sizes      = image_resize_dimensions( $img_info[0], $img_info[1], $size_data['width'], $size_data['height'], $size_data['crop'] );

        // defaults to px units - can't get changed, as applying units is not possible
        $hwstring       = ' '.trim( image_hwstring( $end_sizes[4], $end_sizes[5] ) );

        // Attributes:
        // Not made required as users tend to do funky things (...and lock screen readers out)
        $attr['alt'] = $attr['alt'] ? ' alt="'.esc_attr( $attr['alt'] ).'"' : '';

        if ( ! $attr['title'] )
        {
            $mime = explode( "/", $img_info['mime'] );
            $attr['title'] = sprintf( __('default image of type: %1$s'), ucfirst( $mime[1] ) );
        }
        $attr['title'] = $attr['title'] ? ' title="'.esc_attr( $attr['title'] ).'"' : '';

        $attr['classes'] = "wp-img-default ".esc_attr( $attr['classes'] ? $attr['classes'] : '' );
        $attr['align'] = $attr['align'] ? "align".esc_attr( $attr['align'] ) : '';
        $attr['size'] = "size-".esc_attr( $attr['size'] );

        // Allow filtering of the default attributes
        $attributes  = apply_filters( 'wp_default_img_attr', $attr );

        // Build class attribute, considering that maybe some attribute was unset via the filter
        $classes  = ' class="';
        $classes .= 'wp-img-default'.esc_attr( $attr['classes'] ? ' '.$attr['classes'] : '' );
        $classes .= $attr['align'] ? ' '.esc_attr( $attr['align'] ) : '';
        $classes .= $attr['size'] ? ' '.esc_attr( $attr['size'] ).'" ' : '" ';

        $url        = trim( $attr['url'] );
        $image      = "<img src='{$url}'{$hwstring}{$classes}{$attr['alt']}{$attr['title']} />";

        // Allow filtering of output
        $image      = apply_filters( 'wp_default_img', $image );

        if ( ! $attr['echo'] )
            return $image;

        return print $image;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```php
function before_imageless_product() {
    if( !has_post_thumbnail( get_the_id() ) ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );
        echo '<div class="no-image">';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'before_imageless_product', 9 );
```

Comment: I don't know WooCommerce well but I'd guess that remove_action would remove the thumbnail for all future products, not just the one without the image?